# Delete rows of existing Excel-File

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsx, openpyxl, delete-row

I am currently writing a script, that should delete records of existing Excel-Files by manipulating the data in memory and then saving it.

What I'm doing is creating different sets of values (of skus) that should be deleted from different Excel-Files.
Most of the script is already in function, the "only" problem is the main function of it: deleting records of existing Excel-Files.

I have tried using openpyxl, but it has no delete_row function and the garbage_collect() function was deprecated (this would have been my worse case decision).

What I would NOT like to do is open the file with XLRD and write it with XLWT. Also I can not use xlwings, because the machine that is running the script is running on Linux (win32 COM wouldn't work for the same reason). And I would not like to use is Pandas (I have tried using this module before, but it was too complex for me yet).

I know that those are pretty hard restrictions, but I still hope that there is a way for me to solve this.

Here is some code examle:

```
    for index, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row))): # I thought that I could use the row index to then delete it with it
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value <> header_xlsx:
                if '"' + cell.value + '"' in set:
                    cell.value = '' # This is where I'd like to delete the row
    ws.garbage_collect() # Optional
```

Please notice that I'm aware that there are many similar questions all over the internet but up until now (and I have looked A LOT) I have not found any "ok" solution.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is some unsupported code for this. It is **unsupported** and I think it could be significantly simplified but should get you get started:

https://bitbucket.org/snippets/openpyxl/qyzKn/sample-code-for-inserting-rows-in-an